# Using python to substitute awk for Linux commands

Tags: python, linux, awk

I am new to Python and I need to learn it for work purposes. I am having trouble figuring out a way to use Python to replace awk for column prints.

For example, I need to print out the date:
root@user:~# date
Mon Jun 24 01:30:08 EDT 2013

But, I only need a certain part of it:
root@user:~# date | awk '{print $2" "$3" "$4" "$5}'
Jun 24 01:30:54 EDT

Is there a way in Python to do this without needing to do the following:
import os
os.system("date | awk '{print $2" "$3" "$4" "$5}'")

I have tried to do an extensive Google/Bing/Ask/Yahoo search and have seemed to have come up short on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to look at the [`datetime.datetime.strftime()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime) function for that particular task.

However, for the more general task of printing out certain fields, you'd use [`.split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and [list slicing](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#slice):

```
date_string = "Mon Jun 24 01:30:08 EDT 2013"
fields = date_string.split()
print ' '.join(fields[1:5]) # Prints "June 24 01:30:08 EDT"
```

Comment: Amber, thanks for the response. This helps if I was looking to statically put in a date as string. What I am looking to do is, run the Linux "date" command and grab the state of it only print certain parts of it

Comment: @GregRobertDutertre Is there a reason you need to run the `date` command, as opposed to using the `datetime` library already built into Python?

Comment: Amber, I think it may be my naivety and I am so used to running that through Linux. I am currently reading up on the datetime function.

Comment: @GregRobertDutertre No worries. I think the `datetime` library (and specifically the `strftime` method I mentioned at the beginning of my answer) may do exactly what you need.

Comment: I figured out what I am looking for. I appreciate the input on this.